# 'cast' issue in mysql with bigint and varchar

Tags: mysql, casting

As can be seen below, using 'cast' with int & char works fine,
but the same commands with bigint & varchar respectively don't.

Is this a known problem in mysql?
I ran into this when using jooq - more details below.

If there are workarounds for this, in mysql or jooq, that would be great.
Thanks!

Version

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.39-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

SQL commands
These two work fine

```
MariaDB [puresw]> select cast(100 as int);
+------------------+
| cast(100 as int) |
+------------------+
|              100 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [puresw]> select cast('abc' as char(32));
+-------------------------+
| cast('abc' as char(32)) |
+-------------------------+
| abc                     |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

These two don't

```
MariaDB [puresw]> select cast(100 as bigint);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'bigint)' at line 1

MariaDB [puresw]> select cast('abc' as varchar(32));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(32))' at line 1
```

Problem caused by SQL query generated by jooq

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'bigint), cast(0 as int), cast('ABC' as varchar), cast('Purity' as varchar), cast' at line 1
Query is:
sql : 'insert into software_version (task_id, controller, group_id, name, version, status) values (cast(? as bigint), cast(? as int), cast(? as varchar), cast(? as varchar), cast(? as varchar), cast(? as varchar))', parameters : [100,0,'ABC','Purity','4.5.2','Available']
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:138) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.9.jar:?]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.9.jar:?]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MySQLStatement.java:268) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.9.jar:?]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:296) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.9.jar:?]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLStatement.java:364) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.9.jar:?]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLPreparedStatement.java:148) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.9.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:916) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:909) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: cast does not support all types http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert
In my experience, in many cases casting to "int" IS casting to "bigint" (according to odbc results).

Comment: How did you construct your jOOQ query? Are you sure you used the appropriate `SQLDialect`? jOOQ gets this right for MySQL and MariaDB if everything is properly configured...

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Please check my response below. It does not look right that mysql breaks - looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It was user error. I was using a jooq context that was configured for H2 database's SQL dialect. Created another jooq context to use with mysql and the problem went away. This is what the jooq section in the dao xml file looks like now:

```
<bean id="jooqSettings" class="org.jooq.conf.Settings">
    <property name="renderNameStyle" value="AS_IS"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jooqConfig" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration">
    <property name="SQLDialect" value="H2"/>
    <property name="settings" ref="jooqSettings"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jooqContext" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext">
    <constructor-arg ref="jooqConfig"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jooqConfigMysql" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration">
    <property name="SQLDialect" value="MYSQL"/>
    <property name="settings" ref="jooqSettings"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jooqContextMysql" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext">
    <constructor-arg ref="jooqConfigMysql"/>
</bean>
```